# Could an incorrectly and incompletely filled-out migration card pose a problem on exit?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, turkey

I'm currently in Turkey with a migration card issued by Georgian immigration when exiting by land. Unfortunately, firstly they misspelt my surname (DEVERSERI rather than DEVECSERI) and secondly they never filled out my ID card number and sex. On the Turkish side, which is very lax at that crossing, this did not pose a problem, so sadly I didn't notice it until I'd re-boarded the bus.

However, I'll be exiting at Sabiha Gökcen airport, which is notably stricter I've heard.

Are these errors likely to pose a problem on exit? If so, what should I do to ensure a hassle-free exit?

[image: 1]

Comment: What does Georgian immigration have to do with Turkey?

Comment: @JonathanReez It's a common migration card issued at Georgian-Turkish land crossings to ID card holders (hence it being bilingual). The green stamp is the Georgian exit stamp, the other one the Turkish entry stamp

Comment: That migration card is specific to that land border crossing. In general Turkey doesn't issue migration cards when arriving by air nor are migration cards collected on exit.

Comment: Absolutely wrong, Turkey **always** issues this card if entering on an ID card (at least at the Atatürk, Sabiha Gökcen and Antalya airports, the Kapikule and Ipsala land crossings and the Haydarpasa and Alanya ferryports), although it looks different at non-Georgian borders. Georgia, meanwhile, may only issue it at Sarpi (haven't crossed into Turkey elsewhere, so don't know), but definitely not at non-Turkish borders

Comment: Did you exit Turkey already?

Comment: @JonathanReez No, staying for another week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just got home, having exited Turkey at Sabiha Gökcen airport.

I handed the ID, migration card and boarding pass to the only available immigration officer (no one else was clearing immigration). He just glanced at the ID for three secs (didn't scan it or look at the migration card), then stamped the boarding pass.